# Android volley request using curl command

Tags: android, curl, android-volley

I want to pass content to a web server on this format

```
curl -H "Content-Type:application/json" -X POST -d {"email":"someone@example.com","first_name":"FName","last_na‌​me":"Lname","passwor‌​d":"pass123"}' 192.xxx.xxx.xxx:1111/register_user
```

This is how I need to pass the values to the server. Can any one help me. How this is possible using volley?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What had you tried so far?

Comment: This is a simple JSON post request, there are a large number of tutorials on this.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can do it in this way

```
 JsonObjectRequest jsonRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, "192.xxx.xxx.xxx:1111/register_user", new JSONObject("{"email":"someone@example.com","first_name":"FName","last_na‌​me":"Lname","passwor‌​d":"pass123"}"),
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject jsonObject) {
         //call successful
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) { //error occur 
                }
            }) {

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
            params.put("Accept", "application/json");
            params.put("Accept-Encoding", "utf-8");
            return params;
        }
    };
    jsonRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
            MY_SOCKET_TIMEOUT_MS,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    mRequestQueue.addToRequestQueue(jsonRequest);
```